# TinyIOC register class with constructor using registered types and specified type

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, tinyioc, freshmvvm

I want to register a class that uses previously registered type in its constructor, but is also has a constructor parameter that needs to be specified.

ConnectionEngine needs to be created with new BackgroundWorkerPoll(1000). How do I do this?

```
        FreshIOC.Container.Register<IFormsDevice, DeviceWrapper>();
        FreshIOC.Container.Register<IBluetoothQuery, BluetoothQuery>();
        FreshIOC.Container.Register<ISuperConnectionManager, SuperConnectionManager>();

        ....................

        var superConnectionManager = FreshIOC.Container.Resolve<ISuperConnectionManager>();
        var bluetoothQuery = FreshIOC.Container.Resolve<IBluetoothQuery>();
        var formsDevice = FreshIOC.Container.Resolve<IFormsDevice>();

        var connectionEngine = new ConnectionEngine(superConnectionManager,
            bluetoothQuery, new BackgroundWorkerPoll(1000), formsDevice);
```

Comment: is this not FreshMVVM?

Comment: Yes it is - FreshMVVM uses TinyIOC

Answer (score 1):

I could do it like this but it seems cumbersome:

```
        FreshIOC.Container.Register<ConnectionEngine>().UsingConstructor(() => 
        new ConnectionEngine(
            FreshIOC.Container.Resolve<ISuperConnectionManager>() as ISuperConnectionManager,
            FreshIOC.Container.Resolve<IBluetoothQuery>() as IBluetoothQuery,
            new BackgroundWorkerPoll(1000), 
            FreshIOC.Container.Resolve<IFormsDevice>() as IFormsDevice));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok- here is the best I can do:

```
            FreshIOC.Container.Register<IFormsDevice, DeviceWrapper>();
            FreshIOC.Container.Register<IBluetoothQuery, BluetoothQuery>();
            FreshIOC.Container.Register<ISuperConnectionManager, SuperConnectionManager>();
            FreshIOC.Container.Register<DeviceConnectionTracker>().AsSingleton();
            FreshIOC.Container.Register<MasterParameterContainer>().AsSingleton();
            FreshIOC.Container.Register<ParsingEngine>().AsSingleton();

            var connectionEngine = FreshIOC.Container.Resolve<ConnectionEngine>(
                new NamedParameterOverloads() { { "poller", new BackgroundWorkerPoll(1000) } });

            FreshIOC.Container.Register<ConnectionEngine>(connectionEngine); // register it for FreshMVVM
```